# Regex for integer or double values

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make a regex to accept both integer and double values (positive and negative).

This is what I have:

```
 @"-?d*(?:\d*\.\d*)?$"
```

Before this is marked as a duplicate question, with all the questions I've checked in SO I end up with the SAME PROBLEM:

```
5 and -5 -> true

5.00 and -5.00 -> true

BUT... 5. and -5. -> true
```

It takes < numbers + point only >, in this case ''5.'' and ''-5.'' as a "valid" numbers. Again, this very same problem was present in other similar answers I've already compiled.

Comment: Try `@"^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$"` if you are checking standalone strings.

Comment: example for 36 or 36.3 `@"(^\d{2}(?:\.\d{1})$)|(^\d{2}$)"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should works for you:

```
@"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
```

Matchs only the dot only when have digits after it.

Comment: May you please give me a fiddle of your pattern? It doesn't work for me https://regex101.com/r/lW9qD1/5

Comment: @Shafizadeh: I tested in C#. For test you will have to remove @ and "s

Comment: Then https://regex101.com/r/lW9qD1/6 .. However I'm not a expert in C# .. Maybe it works perfectly in C# ... btw I think there is a misunderstood for me or you ... I think OP wants to return `false` for `5.`

Answer (score 1):

Here you are this regex to match both integer and double values (positive and negative):

```
-?\d+[\.?\d+]*
```

explanation:

- first check for negative sign
- second check for any digits
- third in brackets check (for zero or more) decimal dot and digits after

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^-?\d(.\d+)?[^.]/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lW9qD1/4)

Comment: doesn't allow all values